# How to convert Emgu.image into image in C#?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, emgucv

How to convert Image< Bgr,Byte > to Image?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't there a .ToImage() function on the EmguCV class? or something with a similar name?

Comment: There is not function like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Image class has a .ToBitmap() method.

So it should be as simple as

```
image1.ToBitmap();
```

Comment: There is not .ToBitmap extansion in Image

Comment: @Michael, I beg to differ http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Converting_to_Bitmap

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the Bitmap property of Emgu Image.

```
Image<Bgr,Byte> img = ....

Bitmap bmp = img.ToBitmap();
```